# How to access field of inheritance parent class in constructor of child class?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have couple classes, players and game, game inherits from players, how may I access players fields within game constructor?

```
class players {
public:
    int pawns[4][4];
}

class game : public players (...)

game::game(pref inpref,
    int inpawns[4][4]
) : 
{
    this->prefs = inpref;
    players::pawns = inpawns;  // <-DOEST WORK, BUT SHOWS WHAT I MEAN
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? C arrays are not assignable like that, this code shouldn't work whether there is some inheritance going on or not.

Comment: Also, as a side note, `players` being a base class for `game` is almost certainly wrong from a software design point of view. Perhaps what you rather want to do is composition.

Comment: You've got it all backwards. `game` is a child class. `players` is a parent class.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jane Doe noted, this does not appear to be a proper inheritance relationship. An example off the top of my head that could work here is class HumanPlayer : public Player and class RobotPlayer : public Player, as both would share many of the same properties of player.

What you are trying to do will not work because array types are not assignable. This is just one of the weird things with C++. One solution is to use a for loop:

```
class Game : public Player {
  Game(int pawn_in[4]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
       pawns[i] = pawn_in[i];
    }
  };
};
```

Or just use a vector. You can assign vector to others, so it's a simpler solution.